# what situation we can go for pragma_exception_init

Tags: oracle11g

Can anybody explain why we need pragma exception init. we have user defined exception which does the same job as pragma. Your answer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

pragma exception_init is used to provide a name to an exception so that you can reference the exception by that name in the exception handler. Only a few of the several thousand Oracle exceptions have predefined names. You can use exception_init to create names for these other exceptions.

see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/errors.htm#BABGIIBI

I am editing my previous answer because I can insert formatted text here.
In your example, you are defining an exception that you are throwing, but what if you want to catch an existing exception that the system is throwing, but is unnamed? In the example that follows, I handle two specific errors 'DATA_NOT_FOUND', and ORA-600, which is a system error (and yes, I have some code that gets these).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE exception_init_demo
AS
    l_routine             VARCHAR2 (30) := $$plsql_unit;
    severe_system_error   EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (severe_system_error, -600);
BEGIN
    -- Execution code goes here
    NULL;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN severe_system_error
    THEN
        -- Severe error, log it, notify the dba, re-raise the exception
        log_error (
            p_application => $$plsql_unit
          , p_routine     => l_routine
          , p_message     => SQLERRM || UTL_TCP.crlf || DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_backtrace ()
        );
        notify_dba;
        RAISE;
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
    THEN
        -- No data was found, this is OK, ignore error and return
        return;
    WHEN OTHERS
    THEN
        -- all other errors we will log and re-raise
        log_error (
            p_application => $$plsql_unit
          , p_routine     => l_routine
          , p_message     => SQLERRM || UTL_TCP.crlf || DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_backtrace ()
        );
        RAISE;
END;
```

Comment: for ex:create or replace procedure proc_pragma_demo
as
i number:=1;
i_greater_than_zero exception;
pragma exception_init(i_greater_than_zero,-1234);
begin
if(i>0) then 
raise i_greater_than_zero;
end if;
exception
when i_greater_than_zero then
dbms_output.put_line('i value is greater than zero:');
end;                                                                                                                         in the above example , even if we do not have the pragma it does the same job. What is the significance of pragma?

Comment: Thanks a lot, Brian . I understood.